# Who each or each who

Tags: word-order

I wrote

> It could be a war over the reign between two important men who each knew himself the true heir of the reign.

One modified it to

> It could be a war over the reign between two important men, **each who** knew himself to be the true heir of the reign

What is the related grammar here?

Comment: You used a pronoun after the relative pronoun _who_ which is supposed to replace it. It's like saying, _"I saw a man who he's tall."_.

Comment: As a side note, other than for particles, prepositions, and some pronouns, it's good style to avoid using the same word twice in a sentence unless you *really* want to draw attention to that word.  Here you used "reign" twice, so try using a synonym instead.  As it turns out, "heir to the reign" is not idiomatic, and you should instead say "heir to the throne".

Comment: Actually "a war over the reign between two important men" is grammatical but not entirely correct since "reign" means "rule".  You don't "war over the reign", but you can "war to see who *will* rule"

Answer (score 2):

Your two sentences seem to be attempts to phrase the thought by using the subjective case *who.*

You present an example in which the objective case of the pronoun *who* is the most useful and clearest choice. When *who* is the object of a preposition, its objective case *whom* is grammatically correct. Although it is less idiomatic in spoken English now than it was 50 years ago, it is still preferred in most writing.

In your example, with *each* as a distributive of *two important men* in the first clause, and with *whom* as the object of the preposition *of* in *each of,* the sentence is clear as a bell:

> It could be a war over the reign between two important men, each of *whom* knew himself to be the true heir of the reign.

---

This is not germane to your question, but *reign* might be replaced by *throne* as more idiomatic, and it need be used only once:

> It could be a war over the *throne* between two important men, each of *whom* knew himself to be the true heir.

Comment: +1. for **over the throne**.  I don't disagree with **each of whom** but to my ear **each, who knew himself to be...** is also viable, though in a somewhat "heightened" old-fashioned register.  Late 18th early 19th century.

Comment: @TRomano I can't grok the comma after _each._ Can you explicate, or is that a typo? I was also thinking of **two important men, each believing himself the true heir.**

Comment: That's  just an oratorical comma. It doesn't contribute to the sense.  See p. 208, four lines up from the bottom, for an example of a similar use of **each**: https://books.google.com/books?id=-RVhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA208&dq=%22each+who%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiajfqV7svPAhXDaz4KHcGxBDU4FBDoAQhWMAo#v=onepage&q=%22each%20who%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano hmm. In that text, we have young men _running_ in the first clause and _striving_ in the second. The OP has only one action undertaken by the "each": _knowing,_  with the "dummy it" the subject of the first clause. So in the OP's example, to mirror that usage, we would have to make the _important men_ the subject of an action in the first clause: **It could be a war over the throne _fought_ between two important men, _knowing each_ himself to be the true heir.** Register-wise, that is positively stratospheric.

Comment: In the OP, the situation is affected by the reflexive.  *There were two suitors, who strove each to win the hand of the fair maiden. When she entered a nunnery, those two suitors, who each had known himself to be the better man, joined the foreign legion.*  Not contemporary AmE or BrE, to be sure, but English of two centuries ago.

Comment: I should say "not contemporary AmE or BrE *as taught*". I would not be surprised to hear: "We saw seven people in the clinic today **who each** had been exposed to the Zika virus."

Comment: @TRomano Right you are. I suppose it is my inner antiquarian that smiles when I see instead (however rarely) _"...each of whom had been exposed..."_ To my ear, this is more rhythmic, musical, and felicitous.